# Extract doubles and integers from string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

When I try this:

```
"12.3 xxx4.56 23yyy".match(/\d+/ig)
```

I get this output:

```
["12", "3", "4", "56", "23"]
```

I would like this:

```
["12.3", "4.56", "23"]
```

What's the correct regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an optional group in the regex to handle this case. Like so:

```
"12.3 xxx4.56 23yyy".match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/ig)
=> Array [ "12.3", "4.56", "23" ]
```

The `(...)?` syntax means that everything inside is optional - if present it will be matched, but if not it won't prevent a match. The `?` alone could also be applied to a single term.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
"12.3 xxx4.56 23yyy".match(/([\d.]+)/g)
```

**`i`** seems to be unnecessary since you are only searching for number **`i`** case insensitive is unnecessary.